# Hide remote Node URL when reverse proxying with Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, ghost

I have a CentOS VPS which is serving HTTP requests via Apache and delivers a HTML site. I am also hosting a Ghost blog on the same VPS, which listens on port 2368. Therefore the main site can be accessed via www.domain.co.uk and the Ghost blog via www.domain.co.uk:2368/blog.

I have configured a Reverse Proxy via Apache so that the port can be hidden from the user, i.e. www.domain.co.uk/blog proxies to www.domain.co.uk:2368/blog.

Is it possible for me to 'hide' the original blog URL so that a user never sees the 2368 port? Therefore, if a user ever accesses www.domain.co.uk:2368/blog this will actually 'redirect' to www.domain.co.uk/blog.

I guess something like a proxy from www.domain.co.uk:2368/blog -> www.domain.co.uk/blog; though this would have to be handled by the node application as it listens on that port?

Virtual Host configuration is as such:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.co.uk
    ServerAlias domain.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.co.uk/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/domain.co.uk/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/domain.co.uk/requests.log combined

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /blog http://127.0.0.1:2368/blog
    ProxyPassReverse /blog http://127.0.0.1:2368/blog
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why don't you just prevent the blog from listening on anything other than localhost? That way it *can't* be accessed except for via domain.co.uk/blog